# Compile issues after imported the required files for RedditKit

Tags: ios, objective-c

After following the directions from [readme](https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit) I am unable to compile my code.

[image: Compile error]

This is my first time using `pod`. What are things that I may have done wrong? How can I check them

Answer (score 0):

Just go to those files and try this `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` as I can see that its giving error even for `CGFloat`. You might also need to import `UIKit`.

This is just a wild guess though